# "Наверное" and "наверно"

Tags: выбор-слова

What is the difference between "наверно" and "наверное"? Is there any slight difference in their meaning or in their usage?

Comment: "наверно" is something you can hear, but never in a written form. It's just like "потому что" and "потомушта".

Answer (score 5):

No difference in meaning.
Usage:

- Written form: `Наверное`.
- Oral form: `Наверно`.

I doubt the last one can be seen in books, articles etc. It's illiterate writing.

Comment: Apropos: Is *наверняка* just a colloquial synonym of *Наверно*?

Comment: Yes, `наверняка` is a synonym too. And also it is literate written form. I saw it in books.

Comment: @Dmitry I do not agree. `Наверняка` has a meaning with more probability, I would translate is as `most likely`. `Наверное` has less probable meaning, I would use it for `probably`

Comment: @cha Yup, you are right. But the difference is too tiny in a plenty of contexts, so I decided to skip mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

It's like a `kind of` and a `kinda` difference. `Наверное` is more formal, but both is acceptable.

Comment: that's just wrong, наверно is not like kinda, it is not acceptable even in any context.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would consider «наверное» to be an archaic form (granted a much better sounding one). Through my entire life i probably have heard/saw it only a few times from elder generation. (I think that this is once again the problem of dictionary writers being way too conservative.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the speech both of these options are the same, because they sounds the same. But if you talk over the last letter clearly, it will be perceived positively. In writing "наверно" looks too folksy.